# Spring boot startup listener

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We are running spring boot application as a background process, so we do not have access to startup log, is there a way to know after the boot startup process is complete?

Answer (score 5):

You can choose to execute some code after spring boot process is finished its startup, when startup completed you can send a notification about startup completed.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Component
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        // You can write your code here.
        // This code will be executed after Spring Boot Startup completed. 

    }
}
```

Just implement the CommandLineRunner as shown above.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner