# Setting model attributes for every action within each controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot

I would like to set three common attributes on my model for each `@RequestMapping` within the many controllers in a Spring Boot application. I have read about `@ModelAttribute` but it needs to be placed within each Controller. I have more than 20 controllers in my application and each having more than 10 `@RequestMapping`.

Is there a way to set such model attributes in one place which gets initialized at the start of the application?

Comment: Introduce a common BaseController class and place the `@ModelAttribute` in the class and let all your controllers extend the BaseController

Comment: That is what a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` can do for you. Or use a `HandlerInterceptor` to add the common data on each request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to execute some code on Spring Boot startup, consider this:

[Spring boot startup listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367390/spring-boot-startup-listener/43368506#43368506)

**But I guess that you really want Controller related behavior**, **I would recommend using a Global Interceptor**.

With global interceptor, you can interfere with the request-response lifecycle in Spring.

It lets you add functionality to request-response life cycle in 3 different points:

1. before a controller handles a request
2. after a handler finished performing its functionality
3. when the view is about to render to the end user.

Just create a class which extends from `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and override one of three methods, with your desired functionality.

For Example:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        request.setAttribute("myFirstAttribute", "MyFirstValueHere");
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

}
```

Here's an example on how to do it with Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired 
  MyInterceptor myInterceptor;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(...)
    ...
    registry.addInterceptor(myInterceptor);
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, the attributes are set on the request rather than the model. Am I right?

Comment: I believe that eventually it's being set also on the model. Using the request parameter

Comment: Will that not involve another step to set them up on the model then?

Comment: No further steps are necessary, the request set parameter will do the job

Comment: I know these parameters are set on the request. I get the values using `request.getAttribute("")`. But I am looking to have them on the model so that I can access them on my jsp. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to access these parameters from your JSP? you should success doing it with my suggested solution, using request.setAttribute

Comment: I mean use my original solution + try to read the parameter on JSP like you normally would with the model attribute

Answer (score 1):

I provide another method by SpringMVC,using the **[HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)**,when you implements it,it provides 3 methods,each of them contains **[HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)**,you can set attribute using `request.setAttribute("xx","yy")`,below are the code:

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest arg0,
            HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception arg3)
            throws Exception {

    }

    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse arg1,
            Object arg2, ModelAndView arg3) throws Exception {
      //you can set attributes here like request.setAttribute("xx","yy")
    }

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Object arg2) throws Exception {
        //you can set attributes here like request.setAttribute("xx","yy")
        return false;
    }

}
```

then,you need to add the custom interceptor to your spring mvc application like below:

```
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping">
   <property name="interceptors">
    <list>
      <!--class of your custom interceptor-->
      <bean class="com.xx.RequestInterceptor"/>
    </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```